# How to implement a counter when using golang's goroutine?

Tags: go

I'm trying to make a queue struct that have push and pop functions.

I need to use 10 threads push and another 10 threads pop data, just like I did in the code below.

Questions:

1. I need to print out how much I have pushed/popped, but I don't know how to do that.
2. Is there anyway to speed up my code? The code is too slow for me.

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

const (
    DATA_SIZE_PER_THREAD = 10000000
)

type Queue struct {
    records string
}


func (self Queue) push(record chan interface{}) {
    // need push counter
    record <- time.Now()
}

func (self Queue) pop(record chan interface{}) {
    // need pop counter
    <- record
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    //record chan
    record := make(chan interface{},1000000)
    //finish flag chan
    finish := make(chan bool)
    queue := new(Queue)
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        go func() {
            for j:=0; j<DATA_SIZE_PER_THREAD; j++ {
                queue.push(record)
            }
            finish<-true
        }()
    }
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        go func() {
            for j:=0; j<DATA_SIZE_PER_THREAD; j++ {
                queue.pop(record)
            }
            finish<-true
        }()
    }
    for i:=0; i<20; i++ {
        <-finish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few things you should fix.

- The methods on the Queue type should have pointer receivers. Otherwise, every method
  call will create a copy of the current queue type and any changes to queue fields will
  not persist beyond the method call itself.
- Waiting for all routines to finish, can be done using a `sync.WaitGroup`. This
  is specifically what it was designed for.
- Maintaining a thread-safe push/pop counter inside the queue type can be done by
  using the `sync/atomic` package.

As far as speed goes, from your example, I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Any optimizations might come up if you elaborate on that a little.

Here is an example I modified from your code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

const SizePerThread = 10000000

type Queue struct {
    records string
    count   int64
}

func (q *Queue) push(record chan interface{}) {
    record <- time.Now()

    newcount := atomic.AddInt64(&q.count, 1)
    log.Printf("Push: %d", newcount)
}

func (q *Queue) pop(record chan interface{}) {
    <-record

    newcount := atomic.AddInt64(&q.count, -1)
    log.Printf("Pop: %d", newcount)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    record := make(chan interface{}, 1000000)
    queue := new(Queue)

    // We are launching 20 goroutines.
    // Let the waitgroup know it should wait for as many
    // of them to finish.
    wg.Add(20)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            for j := 0; j < SizePerThread; j++ {
                queue.push(record)
            }
        }()

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            for j := 0; j < SizePerThread; j++ {
                queue.pop(record)
            }
        }()
    }

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish.
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jimt, but i'm not quite understand what you mean by **the Queue type should have pointer receivers**, could you give me a link on golang's doc? i can't find any, Thanks again.

Comment: @MrROY: This section of Effective Go discusses the difference: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values. Essentially, if the receiver is (T), your method gets a *copy* of the object it is called from and therefore cannot change it. If the receiver is (*T) it gets a pointer to it.

Comment: In cases where the number of go-routines is not strictly known at compile time, is there any reason to not call
`wg.Add(1)`
`defer.wg.Done()` in each created goroutine?

Comment: @matthias: No reason at all. I used a single call to Add() because the number of routines were known before hand and thus was able to reduce the amount of necessary function calls.

Comment: @matthias: I should probably revise my comment. Calling `wg.Add(1)` inside each goroutine is in principle doable. But it should be noted that there is no guarantee that the goroutine will be scheduled for execution before the calling thread reaches the `wg.Wait()` part.

In some rare situations this might mean that the `WaitGroup` counter has not yet been incremented and the call to `wg.Wait()` completes prematurely. This constitutes a race condition and should probably be avoided. You can safely call `wg.Add(1)` right before launching a given goroutine though.

Answer (score -5):

Answer to question 1:  As jimt suggested, sync/atomic has functions for atomically updating a counter, which may be useful to you.

Answer to question 2: Reduce the value of DATA_SIZE_PER_THREAD, or better yet, use the program

```
package main
func main() {}
```

which produces the same output as your program in a more efficent way.

Seriously though, I understand you have written a small program to explore some concepts.  Your program contains a number of issues however.  This is not the time to worry about speed, it is the time to learn some fundamental concepts.

Comment: Not a helpful answer at all.